# Thread with an interval

Tags: c++, winapi, intervals

I have a robotcell with 4 robots in it. A so called "update thread" (I hope you know what I mean) reads the coordinates of the roboters and puts them in a data structure after a specific interval e.g. 1000 ms.

Finally we have a thread for each robot (so 4) (again each have different read interval times) which reads the coordinates and calculates the trajectory. I have to use win32api functions and I will use Critical Sections for the solution.

I have never done anything with time intervals in C++, so can anybody show me examples how to do that?

Best regards
naruto90

Comment: Forget the threads and do it all with a timer

Comment: Well, at least the "update thread" anyway. It can use a timer to update the coordinates. But it may still make sense to have each robot in its own thread, depending on what the robots are actually doing. If you really want the "update" to be in its own thread, have a look at `CreateWaitableTimer()` and `WaitForSingleObject()`.